# Meteor 1.3 server folder

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm confused about the [new Meteor 1.3 app folder structure](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html)

It seems that all the server code is now in the `/imports` folder instead of the `/server` folder. The server folder only contains imports for the server.

In previous versions of Meteor, the server folder contained the publications as well as configuration code for certain packages, such as the accounts-ui package.

Am I missing something or does Meteor 1.3 completely change the way the app is meant to be structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything, 1.3 does change the whole zen of the folder structure. `/imports` contains both server and client code. You're meant to have a `main.js` in the `/client` and `/server` directories that actually imports what each needs. There is no `/lib` anymore.

The good news, however, is that MDG has allowed 1.3 to continue to import everything from the 1.2.1 and earlier directory structures so you don't need to restructure everything right away.

Answer (score 0):

server automatically load first when you put it in server folder. That's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can still put server only code inside a 'server' folder in the new folder structure and it'll only be available to the server. That's where you'd put files which contain sensitive data that you don't want served to the client.

Similarly, files inside a 'client' folder will still only get loaded to the client.